# CSS position and opacity styles interfering with hover and click events

Tags: css, events, opacity

Recently I was playing around with a custom modal and I was having difficulty with dismissing it.

Basically there is an anchor tag with an absolute position placed on a div with a relative position. Css hover styles were not applied to it when the mouse was clearly above the anchor also the click event was not being fired.

Examples:

[Defective Dismiss Anchor](http://jsfiddle.net/zPgj8/8/)

[Working Dismiss Anchor](http://jsfiddle.net/zPgj8/7/)

The difference between these two examples is in the css

**In the defective case** the following styles are present

```
.modalDialog
{
   /* ... */
   -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
   -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
   transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
   pointer-events: none;
}
.modalDialog:target
{
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

In the working examples all of these styles have been removed, but everything else stays the same.

My original assumptions about z-index being the culprate proved to be untrue, also I am doubting that fixed and relative positions are to blame (unconfirmed), it looks like opacity is to blame.

I realize why the removed styles are not needed, but I don't understand why they were preventing the hover and click events from firing?

An explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `pointer-events: none` that causes the problem.

This property controls how elements respond to mouse events, in this case hover and click.

It looks like it's tried to be overridden on the `:target` selector, but this won't work in this case, because `.modalDialog:target` means 'when the url is #modalDialog'.  But, that .modalDialog doesn't have an ID so it can't be a target anyway.

From CSS tricks:

> The :target pseudo selector in CSS matches when the hash in the URL and the id of an element are the same.

This is a fiddle update with just the pointer-events CSS rules removed, and it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/zPgj8/11/

Comment: david is exactly right. I just wanted to add that the actual cause is the pointer-event:auto on the anchor style which is forced to inherit it's parent's (pointer-events: none). You can still keep the pointer-events:none for the parent div and specify something different for the anchor such as pointer-events:all

Comment: Yes I see that now. This article lead me astray http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/

Comment: Also I did not know about the :target pseudo selector match rules